# Asp Mvc Model doesnt exist

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hello I am sure this has been asked before but I cannot find the resolution.

[image: Error Model doesnt exist]

The model that gets used

```
public class TaskList : Base
{
    public TaskModel taskModel;
    public List<Task> tasks;

    public TaskList(string role, int userId) : base(role, userId)
    {
        taskModel = new TaskModel(userId,role);
    }

    public void GetTasks(int skip,int take)
    {
        tasks = taskModel.GetTasks(skip, take);
    }

}
```

The controller

```
public ActionResult TaskListPartial(int skip, int take)
    {
        var taskList = new TaskList(role,userId);
        taskList.GetTasks(skip, take);
        return View(taskList);
    }
```

Web.config compilation part

```
<system.web>
<compilation>
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

How do I get the Model to resolve so I can get intellisense?

Comment: If you created the model after you opened this view, you normally have to close and reopen the view. Same is true if you add namespaces to the Views/web.config file.

Comment: What is the -1 for? I have tried to shutdown VS and re-open all with no luck. Is there anything that I need to add to the web.config to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

It show error because in view you have only **single model class** in namespace and in logic you are going to get value from **list of object class**.

Please **define your view model as**:

```
@model List<wrikeMVCNoAuth.ViewModel.Tasks.TaskList>
```

Answer (score 0):

I apologise for the mistake I was under the impression that I didnt have to compile the project each time to get the intellisense to display int he views.

Once I had a successful compile everything came back.